# executeInTransaction=false does not appear to work from gradle flywayMigrate

Tags: transactions, flyway, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to run a sql migration step which loops and commits.  When I run the sql interactively in an auto-commit sessions - everything works and when I cancel the data for the loops that have been completed is committed.

However when I try to do this from flyway I get an error.

```
ERROR: invalid transaction termination
    Where: PL/pgSQL function migrate_item_outlet_sales() line 37 at COMMIT
```

I get this same error from the interactive session, if I change it to be transactional. So I tried adding a configuration V_xxxx.sql.conf containing executeInTransaction=false, but that made no difference.

I was suspicious that it wasn't even using my conf file, so I've tried adding 'xxxx=false' expecting that it should fail with some invalid propery complaint, but it still carried on.

I'm using the gradle plugin and version 6.0.8 and Postgres 12 db.

Is it really not executing a transaction or am I right in my suspicion that the conf is being ignored?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the flywayVersion - the executeInTransaction configuration was not supported in that version. Running with latest 7.0.2 gives the correct expected behaviour.